# Install ansible on HP UX

Tags: ansible, hp-ux

I'm new to ansible and I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to install ansible on HP-UX 11.31 machine.

I tried google it, but I was not able to find if / how it can be done.

I have Python installed on the machine.

Thanks,
Boaz.

Comment: Are you going to use HP-UX as your Ansible control machine?

Answer (score 2):

HP-UX can be managed by ansible just fine.
You just need to:

1. Install Python 2 (can be found in official HP-UX Internet Express bundle)
2. Copy rsa key (with ssh-copy-id or just upload it with some other tool)
   That's, basically it.

If you want to setup control machine... just use Linux for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if anyone's tested HP-UX, but it does meet [the listed requirements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#control-machine-requirements):

> Currently Ansible can be run from any machine with Python 2.6 or 2.7 installed (Windows isn’t supported for the control machine).
>
> This includes Red Hat, Debian, CentOS, OS X, any of the BSDs, and so on.

You should be able to just follow [the pip installation instructions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#latest-releases-via-pip) or, if necessary, [the instructions to install directly from source](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#running-from-source).